# Power Query Facebook Access Token

Tags: excel, facebook-graph-api, facebook-access-token, powerquery

I am trying to query the feed of a Facebook group page using Microsoft Power Query.

This particular query requires an access token. I have tried it out successfully in Facebook's Graph API Explorer, however it seems that Power Query does not include the access token when querying the Facebook Graph API. Thus Power Query is returning the "[DataSource.Error] The returned value has no columns." message. Any ideas on how to include\refresh the access token within Excel?

Answer (score 0):

Power Query absolutely does include the access token when using the Facebook Graph API. However, the set of queries that Facebook allows us to run is considerably smaller than what you can do via the API explorer. This is probably why you don't get any data.

I find that the best way to explore or troubleshoot this kind of issue is to use a tool like Fiddler to see the network traffic as the requests are made.